# Is it possible to draw a line chart in chart.js with multiple lines and **multiple lables**

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, chart.js

Suppose x1={1,4,7,9} | y1={10,20,35,40}  and x2={2,3,6,9} | y2={15,23,30,35}. Now I want to draw a **line chart in chart.js** for it.

P.S. Scatter chart is not a solution because my website is generating data dynamically so I have to provide data in array only and scatter requires the data in very sophisticated manner.

My simple question is by any way, can we have different x axis points in line chart for different lines??

code for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>

<script>
var xValues1 = [50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150];
var yValues1 = [7,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,14,14,15];

var xValues2 = [54,64,74,84,94,104,114,124,134,144,154];
var yValues2 = [8,9,9,10,10,10,11,12,15,15,16];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xValues1,
    datasets: [{
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
      data: yValues1
    },
    {
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
      data: yValues2
    }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:16}}],
    }
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

(for yvalues2, I want xvalues2)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second X axis for your other labels:

```js
const xValues1 = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150];
const yValues1 = [7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 14, 14, 15];

const xValues2 = [54, 64, 74, 84, 94, 104, 114, 124, 134, 144, 154];
const yValues2 = [8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 15, 15, 16];

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: yValues1,
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: yValues2,
        borderColor: 'orange',
        xAxisID: 'x2' // Match dataset to other axis
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          type: 'category',
          labels: xValues1,
          id: 'x',
          display: true // Set to false to hide the axis
        },
        {
          type: 'category',
          labels: xValues2,
          id: 'x2',
          display: true // Set to false to hide the axis
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it not possible to have a single X-axis to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Yes but that would be way more hacky than using a second x axis and hiding it, then you will need to manipulate the tooltip so that it checks which dataset it is, then get the correct labels

Comment: The other option, best solution would be to use a linear scale and use object notation with x and y but you say its impossible (idk why since you alsready have the data just need to map it) and you dont want that solution